# Draggable item always goes down by around 80px

Tags: dart, flutter

I have strange behavior with a draggable item.

Each time I drag it on my stack, it goes down by around 80px (this is an approximation and maybe with another phone it could be something else) down from the drop position. The x value seems ok to me.

Here is the code:

```
class GesturePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GesturePageState createState() => _GesturePageState();
}

class _GesturePageState extends State<GesturePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Gesture"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          DragBox(Offset(0.0, 80.0)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DragBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final Offset initPosition;    
  DragBox(this.initPosition);

  @override
  DragBoxState createState() => DragBoxState();
}

class DragBoxState extends State<DragBox> {
  Offset position = Offset(0.0, 0.0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    position = widget.initPosition;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: position.dx,
      top: position.dy - 80.0,
      child: Draggable(
        data: widget.itemColor,
        child: Container(
          child: Image.asset('images/item.png'),
        ),
        onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
          setState(() {
            position = offset;
          });
        },
        feedback: Container(
          child: Image.asset('images/item.png'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Anyone understand what is going on?

Also, is there a way to be able to see the x and y coordinates live when dragging the item?

**Edit:**
Look for the 80.0 in the source code. This fixed my issue, but only for one emulator type. There is also another interesting code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255869/flutter-drag-and-drop-with-grid)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the thing is pretty simple. The 80 difference that you are having in y axis includes

```
24 px = For Status bar
56 px = For App bar / Navigation bar

Total = 80 px
```

And that's because you are receiving global position, you need to convert this to local position. Here is what you should do.

```
RenderBox referenceBox = context.findRenderObject();
Offset localPosition = referenceBox.globalToLocal(yourGlobalOffset);
```

**Edit:**

1. Make your `Positioned` as the children of `Stack`.
2. Replace your with mine

   ```
   onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
     setState(() {
       RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
       _position = renderBox.globalToLocal(offset);
     });
   },
   ```

Comment: Hi @CopsOnRoad, I am bit lost. I tried to add your 2 lines inside onDraggableCanceled, changed the 'yourGlobalOffset' by 'offset' and assigned to 'position' the offset value. This is worst! I understand I need to use 2 lines, but it seems that I don't use them properly.

Comment: Hi @CopsOnRoad, it works partially. I have 2 images. One at (0.0, 0.0) and a second at (200.0, 0.0). If move the first one, everything is perfect, but when moving the second one down to the Y axis, the Y value is right, but the X becomes something near 0.0! Then, after, I can move both perfectly! Any thought about why globalToLocal screw the second image X value? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @CopsOnRoad. You got it!

Comment: I had to do tricks in the previous answer (`differenceY` and `isChecked` if you remember) because I used your post which had `Positioned` at the top of the widget tree. Then I had to debug and found that `Positioned` needs to be placed in `Stack`.