# Flutter : Drag Widgets across screen (Not Drag and Drop)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state, flutter-android, flutter-positioned

I want to just drag widgets across screen, not drag and drop.

But, whenever I leave it and start dragging again, it starts getting drag from the position it started with. As if it was `reset`.

My guess is build is called again and again, so it automatically uses the `original position values`. How do I fix this? What should the code be?

So in other words, `position` is set to `(100, 100)` after the `DragEvent` ends. And then next drag start from `(100, 100)` instead of the last position widget was dropped to.

I also tried this with `GlobalPosition`, but getting same results.
Here is my code :

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  double x1 = 100.0;
  double x2 = 200.0;
  double y1 = 100.0;
  double y2 = 200.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Drag widget on screen'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: x1,
            top: y1,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
                setState(() {
                  x1 = details.localPosition.dx;
                  y1 = details.localPosition.dy;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 64,
                height: 64,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: x2,
            top: y2,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
                setState(() {
                  x2 = details.localPosition.dx;
                  y2 = details.localPosition.dy;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 64,
                height: 64,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Drag Widgets across screen]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @anirudh i am getting my expected output, just that the widgets reset their positions once a `DragEvent` ends.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255869/flutter-drag-and-drop-with-grid) answer your question?

Comment: The question itself is asking for a `snap` drop where other widgets make space for it, just like when we arrange `App Icons` on home screen. So, the question is unrelated. THOUGH, someone gave a solution that might work for me! Thanks @anirudh for sharing this!

Comment: @anirudh the post you shared has a response unrelated to that person's question, but it works for me! Thanks!

Comment: Haha nice , hope it helped

Answer (score 7):

```
  double x1 = 100.0, x2 = 200.0, y1 = 100.0,
  y2 = 200.0, x1Prev = 100.0, x2Prev = 200.0, y1Prev = 100.0,
  y2Prev = 100.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Drag widget on screen'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: x1,
            top: y1,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onPanDown:(d){
                x1Prev = x1;
                y1Prev = y1;
              },
              onPanUpdate: (details) {
                setState(() {
                  x1 = x1Prev + details.localPosition.dx;
                  y1 = y1Prev + details.localPosition.dy;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 64,
                height: 64,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: x2,
            top: y2,
            child: GestureDetector(
               onPanDown:(d){
                x2Prev = x2;
                y2Prev = y2;
              },
              onPanUpdate: (details) {
                setState(() {
                  x2 = x2Prev + details.localPosition.dx;
                  y2 = y2Prev + details.localPosition.dy;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 64,
                height: 64,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```